# Generating Vectors under Constraints on 1 and 2 norm

Tags: algorithms, analytic-geometry, computational-geometry

**Update:** I left out some important information in my previous description... I am actually dealing with a special problem, which is better described as follows:

Given user-specified parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (where $0 \lt\alpha \lt 1/(n+1) $, $\beta \gt 0$), generate at least one $n$-vector $A=[a_1,a_2,....,a_n]$ such that: 
 $(a_1)^2 + (a_2)^2 + \cdots + (a_n)^2  = (\beta - \alpha)\alpha $, 
where $\alpha = 1 - (a_1 + a_2 + .... + a_n) $,
and each component of $A$ is restricted to lie in the interval $(\alpha,1)$.

*Note that I am using rounded parentheses to indicate that the interval does not include its boundary points.

---

While working on a broader problem in developing a computer program, I realized that I could save a lot of time if I could generate n-vectors (for fixed n), subject to the following constraints:

1) the 1-norm of each vector must be equal to some user-specified scalar lambda (note: lambda will always be between 0 and 1)

2) the square of the 2-norm of each vector must be equal to some user-specified scalar phi (note: phi will always be positive)

3) Each vector component must be between 0 and 1

Of course, there are also logical constraints on the choices of lambda and phi given the above constraints... but I suppose we can assume that these parameters are well chosen.

Ultimately, I am searching for a way to accomplish this (or come as close as possible to accomplishing this) via an automated process. I'm not sure how to 'get off the ground', however.

Comment: Do these vectors need to be distributed in any particular way?

Comment: Ross - no, the vectors simply need to follow these constraints.

Comment: So you just need one vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies them?

Comment: Actually, yes - having at least one such n-vector would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer using geometry for $\mathbb{R}^2$ (also letting the 2-norm be $\phi$ for convenience):

Solving $x+y=\lambda$ and $r=\phi$ gives
$$
x = r \cos\theta \\
x = r \sin \theta \\
\theta = 2\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{2-\dfrac{\lambda^2}{\phi^2}}}{\dfrac{\lambda}{\phi}+1}\right)\right)
$$

For the n-dimensional case, just make $x_1=x$, $x_2=y$, other $x_i=0$.

More complicated method(not completely tested!):

- Define $x$ as $x_i = \frac{\lambda}{n} \forall i$.
- Choose a nonzero, elementwise positive random vector $y$ by your method of choosing, that is also not a scalar multiple of $x$.
- Choose a set of $n-1$ basis vectors $\left\{a_i\right\}$ for the hyperplane defined by $\sum x_i = \lambda$, and create the projection matrix  $P_a = AA^T$, where $\left\{a_i\right\}$ are the columns of $A$.
- Compute the vector $y_p = P_ay$, and subsequently scale the vector $y_p$ such that $||y_p'||_2^2 = \phi^2 - \frac{\lambda^2}{n}$
- The vector $z = x + y_p'$ will now have the desired properties.

Explanation: 
Since $||x||_1 = \lambda$ and $y_p'$ is a scaled projection of $y$ onto the corresponding hyperplane of constant $\lambda$, $z$ will be on said hyperplane and have $||z||_1 = \lambda$.

Also, note that $x$ and $y_p'$ are orthogonal. Thus, $||z||^2_2 = ||x||^2_2 + ||y_p'||^2_2 = \frac{\lambda^2}{n} + \phi^2 - \frac{\lambda^2}{n} = \phi^2$.

Comment: Thank you Ross - this is very helpful. In looking through your response, I've realized that I may be dealing with a somewhat simpler case (which I previously failed to specify). I have provided an updated description of my problem within the body of the question.

Comment: Your problem statement seems incomplete in terms of bounds on coefficients. For example, $n=2, \alpha=0.5$ implies that $a_i > 0.5$ but $\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i = 0.5$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Hm. One piece of information that may help is that I am focusing on cases in which n>=3. But, for a case with n=2, one 'valid' vector satisfying these conditions would be [0.6, 0.3], with alpha=0.1

Comment: I have modified the problem statement to specify that alpha must be less than 1/(n+1)